# How to create key pair with gnupg using node js programmatically?

Tags: node.js, encryption, gnupg, pgp

How can I used nodejs sdk of `gnupg` for creating key pair programmatically and storing them in the database and encrypting decrypting files, I couldn't find any documentation or source to do this.

I'm using this nodejs libary:

https://github.com/drudge/node-gpg

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this, let me know If you find any solution. Thanks

Comment: @DaisySaxena sure.